# Product of two rational numbers is an integer.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The product of two rational numbers is $16$. What relations can we build between the two numbers?

---

My attempt:

$ab = 16$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$
$$\implies \frac{p}{q}\cdot\frac{s}{r} = 16$$ where $p,q,r,s\in \mathbb{Z}$
$\implies 16qr = ps$

I am stuck here. How to build relations given we know all are integers in the latter equation?

---

The reason I am asking this is as follows. I am stuck on an equation of the type:
$f(x)g(x) = 16$ and both of these are quadratic functions, making the equation a quartic equation. One fact I know though, is that x can only be a rational number which means $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}$. Using this fact can I build some relations to solve this equation or do I have no choice but to solve the quartic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what kind of relation you are looking for in particular. But something like $r \cdot \frac{16}{r}=16$, where $r \in \Bbb{Q} \setminus\{0\}$ is what makes most sense.

Comment: im looking for an exhaustive list of all relations we can make between a and b. Like 4p = q and 4s = r etc etc

Comment: Your questions is asking for relation between the **rational numbers** whose product is $16$ and your comment is about relations between the integers used in the representation of those rational numbers.

Comment: ok the real question goes like this. f(x)g(x) = 16, where f(x),g(x)are quadratics ... But it is given the domain and range is rational and not real. If it was $x \in R$,  solving a quartic would be very tedious. I was hoping I could make use of the fact that $x \in Q$ so that I can build a finite set of relations.

Comment: i'd say that the product being $16$ *is* the relation.  I'm not sure what the question is asking but the only interpretation I can see is that $R\subset \mathbb Q\times \mathbb Q$ where $R = \{(r,\frac {16}r)| r\in \mathbb A\}$.    $r R s \iff (r,s)\in R \iff rs = 16;r,s\in \mathbb Q$.  I'm not sure how else to interpret the question.

Comment: "im looking for an exhaustive list of all relations we can make between a and b. Like 4p = q and 4s = r etc etc"  Um.... $r = \frac {16}r$ is the one any only.  Why are you not considering that and why aren't you ending there?

Answer (score 1):

I will use a different set of notations.

**Proposition.** If $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers such that

$$ ab = cd, $$

then there exist positive integers $r,s,t,u$ such that

$$ a=rs, \quad b=tu, \quad c=rt, \quad d=su. $$

This may be easily modified to include equations such as

$$ 16ab = cd $$

by solving for

$$ AB = cd, $$

with $A=2^e \cdot a$ and $B=2^{4-e} \cdot b$, $e \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Answer (score 0):

$ps$ is a rearrangement of the prime factorization of $qr$ with the additional factors from $2^4$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you should care about the integer representations of the rationals.  But anyway.

Let $j,k$ be any two relatively prime odd numbers.

Then $p= 2^aj; q=2^bk; s=2^ck; r=2^dj$.

$a,b,c,d$ must have the following conditions.  If $a = 0$ then $d=0$, $c\ge 4$ and $b=c-4$.

If $c=0$ then $b=0$ and $a \ge 4$ and $d=a-4$.

If neither $a$ nor $c$ equal $c$ then neither is larger than $3$ and $a+c=4$ and $b = d =0$.